# SQL SERVER - Using DATEDIFF with subquery column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that looks like:

```
SELECT
    col1
    ,...
    ,col3
    ,(SELECT col3 FROM table where <clause>) AS MinPickTime
    ,(SELECT col3 FROM table where <clause>) AS MaxPickTime
    ,DATEDIFF(d, MinPickTime, MaxPickTime)
FROM table
```

However the DATEDIFF line does not like the alias columns.

In short, how do I give DATEDIFF an alias column derived by a subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [derived tables](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1042/using-derived-tables-to-simplify-the-sql-server-query-process/) concept to access alias name.

```
SELECT  col1
    ,...
    ,col3,
     MinPickTime,
     MaxPickTime ,
DATEDIFF(d, MinPickTime, MaxPickTime)
FROM (
SELECT
    col1
    ,...
    ,col3
    ,(SELECT col3 FROM table where <clause>) AS MinPickTime
    ,(SELECT col3 FROM table where <clause>) AS MaxPickTime

FROM table
)z
```

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6698069d-7d1f-42e4-9136-7247842d3481/temporary-table-vs-table-variable-vs-derived-table?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 0):

```
with temp as (SELECT
    col1
    ,...
    ,col3
    ,(SELECT col3 FROM table where <clause>) AS MinPickTime
    ,(SELECT col3 FROM table where <clause>) AS MaxPickTime
FROM table)

select DATEDIFF(d,MaxPickTime,MinPickTime) from temp
```

Comment: It is always more helpful if you explain how your code works.