# MySQL - Cannot reference result of a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

Hit a roadblock and hoping someone here is able to help please?

edit: DB<>FIDDLE : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=c73f8ec9a60f530fe4ad489dc743f9b9

I have 3 tables:

1. marks - which uses grades;
2. target - which also uses grades;
3. grades - a lookup for grades to points.

What I am trying to do is calculate the total points for grades within the marks table, then calculate the total target points by multiplying the points value for the target by the number of grades within the marks table for a given person (adno).

I'm able to sum and count the points values from the marks table without a problem, but as I've used an inner joint for the marks to grades already I cannot add a further one for target to grades so I've used a subquery.

However when I try to use the result of subquery (EDIT single_target_points , not target_points as I originally posted) in the calculation in the line straight after it I get the error :

> [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'single_target_points' in 'field list'

This is the query I am trying:

```
SELECT
       marks.adno,
       Sum(grades.points) AS total_points,
       Count(grades.points) AS no_of_subjects,
       (SELECT grades.points FROM targets INNER JOIN grades ON targets.grade = grades.grade WHERE targets.adno = marks.adno GROUP BY grades.points) AS single_target_points,
    single_target_points*no_of_subjects AS target_points
FROM
    marks
INNER JOIN grades ON marks.resultvalue = grades.grade
INNER JOIN targets ON targets.adno = marks.adno
GROUP BY
    marks.adno
```

Comment: It's a mistake to think like this 'when I try to use the result of subquery (target_points) in the calculation in the line straight after it I get the error' , target_points is not available further down the select..

Comment: Please post table description some data and expected result to give a better idea. Use https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: Referencing subquery columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36938253/mysql-referencing-subquery-columns)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=c73f8ec9a60f530fe4ad489dc743f9b9

Answer (score 0):

This will resolve the query for you, but not sure what you are doing is completely accurate.  I took your in-line query and made it a subquery including the "adno" (person id) to get all distinct points.  Using that and JOINING based on the person like the others.

```
SELECT
        m.adno,
        Sum(g.points) AS total_points,
        Count(g.points) AS no_of_subjects,
        SUM( TP.single_target_points * g.points) AS target_points
    FROM
        marks m
            JOIN grades g
                ON m.resultvalue = g.grade
            JOIN students s
                ON m.adno = s.adno
            JOIN targets t
                ON m.adno = t.adno
                JOIN
                ( SELECT distinct
                        t2.adno,
                        t2.grade,
                        g2.points single_target_points 
                    FROM 
                        targets t2 
                            JOIN grades g2
                                ON t2.grade = g2.grade ) TP
                    on t.adno = TP.adno
                    and t.grade = TP.grade
    GROUP BY 
        m.adno
```

Now, that being said, it looks like you are trying to compute a person's GPA (grade point average).  If you can EDIT your existing post and provide samples of data (use spaces to align, not tabs) even if fictional names (but not necessary since things here are all ID values and otherwise not private).  It would help to see the basis of what computations are going on.  If not done correctly, you will get Cartesian results and skew your points due to multiple entries * multiple entries = oversized expected answer values.

Also, I [Updated your dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=2d0e725981049c723aad10d406e6faf9).  You inserted into adno instead of students the sample records, inserted into targets the grades, so those tables were blank.  I had to correct that.  Then changed grades to integer since doing math (via sum( g.points)).  Best to use proper data types vs everything as character.

At least the queries are now working, but does not make sense if this is GPA calculations -- as far as I know and have done for U.S. college transcript purposes.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll try it shortly.  I've made a dbfiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=79d6b039d8d802f2b93c54ea7b2581b9

Comment: @IanGale, no Students table defined in dbfiddle

Comment: Sorry, I removed it for simplicity for the main question, this fiddle has that table: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=c73f8ec9a60f530fe4ad489dc743f9b9

Comment: @IanGale, your grades table you have POINTS as CHARACTER.  If you are trying to perform math by multiplying, should they be numeric/integer type field instead?  I see you are doing count which should not care, just trying to assess best data type for purpose.