# mysql left join where Unknown column '' in 'where clause

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    JSON_PRETTY(
      JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
          'room', id,
          'title', title,
          'chat', chats
        )
      )
    ) AS data
  FROM (
    SELECT
      r.id AS id,
      r.title AS title,
      JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
          'created_at', c.created_at,
          'content', c.content
        )
      ) AS chats

    FROM chat_room r

    LEFT JOIN (
      select * from chat
      where chat.parent = r.id <========== unknown
      order by chat.id DESC limit 0, 1
    ) c
    ON r.id = c.parent

    GROUP BY c.parent, r.id ORDER BY r.id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
  ) AS c
```

why this r.id unknown ?

Comment: Please post your schema

Answer (score 0):

Some DBMS allow that in **subqueries** (... LEFT JOIN **(select * ...) c**  ...) to reference tables that are outside the subquery (here r) (e. g. MS SQL with CROSS APPLY), but others not or only under certain conditions. [MySQL does not allow to reference a top level table in a subquery in the FROM...JOIN section as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37004689/593045).

This is an approach without any such DBMS dependent specialities and should work with your DBMS too - does it work?

```
SELECT
  JSON_PRETTY(
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
      JSON_OBJECT(
        'room', id,
        'title', title,
        'chat', chats
      )
    )
) AS data
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    r.id AS id,
    r.title AS title,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
      JSON_OBJECT(
        'created_at', c.created_at,
        'content', c.content
      )
    ) AS chats

  FROM chat_room r

  LEFT JOIN -- get first the entry with the maximum chat.id
  (
   select max(ci.id) maxid, ci.parent
   from chat ci
   group by ci.parent
  ) cg
  ON  cg.parent = r.id
  LEFT JOIN chat c -- as second step then the other values of chat table
  ON c.id = cg.maxid AND cg.parent = r.id

  GROUP BY c.parent, cg.parent, cg.maxid, r.id ORDER BY r.id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
) AS cout
```

The trick is that we cannot achieve everything with one join.
Sometimes we need 2 joins to the same table.

Comment: This doesnt explain what the OP is asking

Comment: @Rohit Gupta Thanks for the hint, I updated the answer with an answer to the OP and explanation of my solution attempt.